# Returning whole document after modifying line - sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to create a script to recurrently modify the value of a variable and then save this modification in another file to run it later. However, when using:

```
sed '0,/pattern/  c\epsilon = ' $VaR $NameOfFile \
 > "NeWFile${VaR2}.txt"
```

It only returns the text from the line it has changed.

An example of my program is:

```
..blablabla..
epsilon = 10
..moreblablabla..
```

After executing my script I get the new file with its name but with only:

```
epsilon = 34
..moreblablabla..
```

I want to change this first occurrence of epsilon for another value and input the whole file with the modification into the new file with a different name.

The script I have written so far is:

```
#!/bin/sh    
echo 'Hello, enter the name of the file you want to process with sed'
read NaMeoFFiLe
echo ''
echo 'Now, you should input the value of epsilon' \
        'you want to start with the loop'
read startepsilonvalue
echo Start epsilon value will be $startepsilonvalue
let lastepsilonvalue=$startepsilonvalue+1 #increase var by 1
echo Last epsilon value is: $lastepsilonvalue
let stteps=$startepsilonvalue*10
let lsteps=$lastepsilonvalue*10
for ((i=$stteps; i<=$lsteps; i+=1)); do
        k=$(bc <<<"""scale=1; $i /10")
        echo $k
        sed '0,/epsilon =/ c\epsilon = '$startepsilonvalue $NaMeoFFiLe \
               > "sample2iter${k}.txt"
done
```

Any other comment on the best practices of the code is also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way the `c\` command works (emphasis mine):

```
    c\ text
    
        Delete the lines matching the address or address-range, and output the 
        lines of text which follow this command.
```

With a slight modification you could limit the change to only the last line of the range:

```
sed -e '0,/epsilon = /{//c\epsilon = '"$startepsilonvalue" -e '}' "$NaMeoFFiLe"
```

(the empty regex `//` re-uses the previous regex, while the trick with `-e` to split the closing brace into a separate expression prevents sed from treating it as part of the change text) or try instead

```
sed '0,/epsilon = .*/s//epsilon = '"$startepsilonvalue"'/' "$NaMeoFFiLe"
```

Comment: Both solutions worked. However, I still do not understand why my code did not work. It is because of the address-range that takes all the lines until the match? Why is that?

Comment: @Nankin yes; the `c` command takes either a single address or a range - when given a range, it deletes all lines in the matching range, not only the line that matches the end of the range.

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation!